# closing angular popup model dialog after operation success

Tags: angular

This is my angular code for model Pop Up,

```
<form #addNewItem="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onNewItemCreate(addNewItem.form.valid)">
        <div class="modal" id="addNewItem" role="dialog"  ng-show="addNewModelShow">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Item</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
              .......
              .......
```

This is how I show this popup ,

```
<a class="dropdown-item add-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNewItem">
```

I have item create function on typescript, in my function , when Item insert is success , I want to close my pop-up model ( from Typescript )

```
onNewItemCreate(isValid: boolean) {
......
......
    if(itemCreatedSuccess) {
        // I want to close pop up here
    } else {
        ....
    }
}
```

> I already tried with `addNewModelShow = false` but doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a functional example in stackblitz? Also if you are using Bootstrap with Angular which uses Jquery i recommend you to give a look to this https://ng-bootstrap.github.io

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap, right?

If so, you can invoke the `hide` routine like this:

```js
$('#addNewItem').modal('hide')
```

Check the full documentation for Bootstrap's modals [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to close modal from your controller side you can use using this way

```
$("#addNewItem").modal("hide");
```